# is there any "android" library to use for HTTP POST, GET

Tags: android, google-app-engine

Is there any  Android library to use for HTTP POST, GET etc. in terms of performance, stability, maturity etc.?

I have an android app i want to submit HTTPS POST requests to a server (GAE).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache HTTPClient is built-in in Andorid. See the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html).

It's stable and mature and it has - in my experience - a good performance.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
            HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams,
                    TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
            HttpPost request = new HttpPut(post_url);
```

Answer (score 0):

depending on what you would like to do you could also check out jsoup from jsoup.org

im using it in several projects and am quite happy with it.